# Django Restframework: What view to use for statistical summary of queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django Restframework provides generic views for lists and single models from querysets. Which view class would be most appropriate for creating an endpoint that serves a statistical summary of a queryset?

I could surely build an APIView from scratch but I would like to reuse most of the settings on the ListAPIView (such as get_queryset, permission_classes, etc.) as well as url parameters.

The endpoints will be organized like this:

```
/api/data/           # data endpoint
/api/data/summary/   # summary endpoint
```

The summary endpoint will provide a single object that is not related to a single model instance.

Thank you for any best practice advice.

Comment: I think building your own APIView class is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I came up with following solution:

```
# pseudo-code !    

class DataView(ListAPIView):
    """Returns a queryset as a serialized and paginated list.
    Set queryset, permissions, etc. here."""

    def get_queryset(self):
        # add complex lookup here
        queryset = self.queryset
        return queryset


class SummaryView(DataView):
    """Overwrite the get method to serve different 
    content, e.g. statistical summary."""

    def summarize(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """This can be moved to a Mixin class."""
        # make sure the filters of the parent class get applied
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        # do statistics here, e.g.
        stats = {'count': queryset.count()}
        # not using a serializer here since it is already a 
        # form of serialization
        return Response(stats)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.summarize(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I´m done that the same way you are suggesting. Just create the response yourself. There is no need for a serializer. It would over complicate the code