# Django Rest Framework group and count POST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to **DRF** and am trying to create some kind of dynamic **serializer** to calculate the objects posted but I cannot find out how to do it.

> models.py

```
class Company(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_founded = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def get_year (self):
        return self.date_founded.strftime("%Y")


    def get_quarter (self):
        x = self.date_founded
        if int(x.strftime("%m")) <= 3:
            return '1'
        elif int(x.strftime("%m")) <= 6 and int(x.strftime("%m")) > 3:
            return '2'
        elif int(x.strftime("%m")) <= 9 and int(x.strftime("%m")) > 6:
            return '3'
        else:
            return '4'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.name)
```

> serializers.py

```
class StatsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    year = serializers.DateField(source='get_year')
    quarter = serializers.CharField(source='get_quarter')
    # total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['year', 'quarter', #'total']
```

> views.py

```
class CompanyStatsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatsSerializer
```

So far my results are:

```
[
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "quarter": "2"
    },
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "quarter": "2"
    },
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "quarter": "2"
    },
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "quarter": "2"
    },
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "quarter": "3"
    },
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "quarter": "3"
    },
 ]
```

however I am looking for something like this:

```
[
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "quarter": "2"
        "total": 4
    },
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "quarter": "3"
        "total": 2
    },
]
```

How can I group and count this values? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What you are looking for are aggregation functions, so check [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) for more info

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a REST endpoint so DRF won't help you here, you need to write it from scratch

Comment: BTW how do you calculate the total, is that total years?

Comment: total should be the common year and quarter, if year and quarter are the same that's counts one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you want is not a REST-like endpoint.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values to understand how to build GROUP BY query in Django.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#extract to understand how to group by year and quarter computed in database.

Finally you need to build an endpoint, please see [Django Restframework: What view to use for statistical summary of queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794983/django-restframework-what-view-to-use-for-statistical-summary-of-queryset) this looks like a duplication of your question.