# Is there a way to add custom data into ListAPIView in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

So I've built an API for movies `dataset` which contain following structure:

**Models.py**

```
class Directors(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'directors'
        ordering = ['-id']

class Movies(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rank = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'movies'       
        ordering = ['-id']

class Actors(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'actors'       
        ordering = ['-id']

class DirectorsGenres(models.Model):
    director = models.ForeignKey(Directors,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='directors_genres')
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    prob = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)    

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'directors_genres'       
        ordering = ['-director']

class MoviesDirectors(models.Model):
    director = models.ForeignKey(Directors,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='movies_directors')
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='movies_directors')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'movies_directors'       
        ordering = ['-director']
        


class MoviesGenres(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='movies_genres')
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)    

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'movies_genres'        
        ordering = ['-movie']


class Roles(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actors,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='roles')
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='roles')    
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)    

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'roles'        
        ordering = ['-actor']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from api.views import getMovies, getGenres, getActors

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.getRoutes),    
    path('movies/', getMovies.as_view(), name='movies'),    
    path('movies/genres/', getGenres.as_view(), name='genres'),
    path('actor_stats/<pk>', getActors.as_view(), name='actor_stats'),    
]
```

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from movies.models import *

class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movies
        fields = '__all__'

class DirectorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Directors
        fields = '__all__'

class ActorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Actors
        fields = '__all__'

class DirectorsGenresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DirectorsGenres
        fields = '__all__'

class MoviesDirectorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movie = MoviesSerializer(many = False)
    director = DirectorsSerializer(many = False)
    class Meta:
        model = MoviesDirectors
        fields = '__all__'

class MoviesGenresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movie = MoviesSerializer(many = False)
    class Meta:
        model = MoviesGenres
        fields = '__all__'

class RolesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movie = MoviesSerializer(many = False)
    actor = ActorsSerializer(many = False)
    class Meta:
        model = Roles
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class getMovies(ListAPIView):
    directors = Directors.objects.all()  
    queryset = MoviesDirectors.objects.filter(director__in=directors)
    serializer_class = MoviesDirectorsSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['director__first_name', 'director__last_name']

class getGenres(ListAPIView):
    movies = Movies.objects.all()  
    queryset = MoviesGenres.objects.filter(movie__in=movies).order_by('-genre')
    serializer_class = MoviesGenresSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['genre']

class getActors(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Roles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RolesSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            actor_id=self.kwargs['pk']
        )
```

Now I want to count number of movies by genre that actor with specific pk played in `getActors` class.
Like the number of movies by genre that actor participated in. E.g. Drama: 2, Horror: 3
Right now I am getting the overall count of movies `count: 2`:

```
GET /api/actor_stats/17


HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 800480,
            "movie": {
                "id": 105231,
                "name": "Everybody's Business",
                "year": 1993,
                "rank": null
            },
            "actor": {
                "id": 17,
                "first_name": "Luis Roberto",
                "last_name": "Formiga",
                "gender": "M"
            },
            "role": "Grandfather"
        },
        {
            "id": 800481,
            "movie": {
                "id": 242453,
                "name": "OP Pro 88 - Barra Rio",
                "year": 1988,
                "rank": null
            },
            "actor": {
                "id": 17,
                "first_name": "Luis Roberto",
                "last_name": "Formiga",
                "gender": "M"
            },
            "role": "Himself"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the optimized way of achieving the following:

- number_of_movies_by_genre
- Drama: 2
- Horror: 3

**UPDATE**

```
class RolesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):    
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    top_genre = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    number_of_movies = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    number_of_movies_by_genre = serializers.SerializerMethodField()    
    most_frequent_partner = serializers.SerializerMethodField() 

class Meta:
    model = Roles
    fields = '__all__'

def get_id(self, obj):
    return obj.actor.id

def get_name(self, obj):
    return f'{obj.actor.first_name} {obj.actor.last_name}'

def get_top_genre(self, obj):      

    number_by_genre = Roles.objects.filter(actor = obj.actor.id
    ).values('movie__movies_genres__genre').annotate( 
        genre = F('movie__movies_genres__genre'),         
        number_of_movies=Count('movie__movies_genres__genre'),  
    )       

    data = [s['number_of_movies'] for s in number_by_genre]

    highest = max(data)

    result = [s for s in data if s == highest]
    
    return result

def get_number_of_movies(self, obj):
    number_of_movies = Roles.objects.filter(actor = obj.actor.id
    ).values('movie__name').count()

    return number_of_movies

def get_number_of_movies_by_genre(self, obj):
    number_of_movies_by_genre = Roles.objects.filter(actor = obj.actor.id
    ).values('movie__movies_genres__genre').annotate(            
        genre=F('movie__movies_genres__genre'),           
        number_of_movies=Count('movie__movies_genres__genre'),            
    ).values('genre', 'number_of_movies')

    return number_of_movies_by_genre    

def get_most_frequent_partner(self, obj):
    partners = Roles.objects.filter(actor = obj.actor.id
    ).values('movie__id')

    
    result = Roles.objects.filter(movie__in = partners
    ).values('actor').exclude(actor=obj.actor.id).annotate(
        partner_actor_id = F('actor'),
        partner_actor_name = Concat(F('actor__first_name'), Value(' '), F('actor__last_name')),
        number_of_shared_movies =Count('actor'),
    ).values('partner_actor_id', 'partner_actor_name', 'number_of_shared_movies')
    
    

    
    return result
```

The problem with that code is: It repeats the results by the number of movies. For instance if the actor have 5 movies the results will be repeated 5 times. Another issue is: in order to get `top_genre` and `most_frequent_partner` I'm using `max()` but then I just get the numbers and not the actual name of genre in (`top_genre`) and actor name in (`most_frequent_partner`). Since I use `max()` in a way to get more than one value. For instance in the `top_genre`: If the actor have `3 Drama, 3 Comedy, 1 Horror, 1 Documentary`, I get the max in that way: `[3,3]`, but how can I get the actual names out of these results? Same goes to `most_frequent_partner`.

Results looks like this so far:

```
{
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "count": 4,
    "pagenum": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 36,
            "name": "Benjamin 2X",
            "top_genre": [
                2,
                2
            ],
            "number_of_movies": 4,
            "number_of_movies_by_genre": [
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": null,
                    "genre": null,
                    "number_of_movies": 0
                },
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": "Documentary",
                    "genre": "Documentary",
                    "number_of_movies": 2
                },
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": "Music",
                    "genre": "Music",
                    "number_of_movies": 2
                }
            ],
            "most_frequent_partner": []
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "name": "Benjamin 2X",
            "top_genre": [
                2,
                2
            ],
            "number_of_movies": 4,
            "number_of_movies_by_genre": [
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": null,
                    "genre": null,
                    "number_of_movies": 0
                },
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": "Documentary",
                    "genre": "Documentary",
                    "number_of_movies": 2
                },
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": "Music",
                    "genre": "Music",
                    "number_of_movies": 2
                }
            ],
            "most_frequent_partner": []
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "name": "Benjamin 2X",
            "top_genre": [
                2,
                2
            ],
            "number_of_movies": 4,
            "number_of_movies_by_genre": [
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": null,
                    "genre": null,
                    "number_of_movies": 0
                },
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": "Documentary",
                    "genre": "Documentary",
                    "number_of_movies": 2
                },
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": "Music",
                    "genre": "Music",
                    "number_of_movies": 2
                }
            ],
            "most_frequent_partner": []
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "name": "Benjamin 2X",
            "top_genre": [
                2,
                2
            ],
            "number_of_movies": 4,
            "number_of_movies_by_genre": [
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": null,
                    "genre": null,
                    "number_of_movies": 0
                },
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": "Documentary",
                    "genre": "Documentary",
                    "number_of_movies": 2
                },
                {
                    "movie__movies_genres__genre": "Music",
                    "genre": "Music",
                    "number_of_movies": 2
                }
            ],
            "most_frequent_partner": []
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to see in the end:

```
{
        "next": null,
        "previous": null,
        "count": 2,
        
        "results": [
            {
                "id": 18 (actor_id),
                "name": Bruce Buffer (actor_name),
                "number of movies": 2, 
                "top genre": Drama, Documentary,
                "number of movies by genre": Drama: 1, Documentary: 1,
                "most frequent partner": partner_actor_id, partner_actor_name, number_of_shared_movies,
            }
            
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I think this post should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018037/django-rest-framework-group-and-count-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, the `number of movies` by `genre` for a given actor what you can do is annotate and count aggregate

```py
return Roles.objects.filter(
            actor_id=self.kwargs['pk']
        ).values('movie__movies_genres__genre').annotate(
            no_of_movies=Count('movie__movies_genres__genre'),
            genre=F('movie__movies_genres__genre'),
        )
```

Here first we filtered roles for a given actor
then [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values) will group by `genre` then annotation is computed over all members of the group that [`count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/) and get `genre`

and you can use `SerializerMethodField` to these calculated results

if you have a huge dataset it will not perform well, but you can create [indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/indexes/) accordingly still it will cost you 2-3 queries

you can learn more about Django [queryset API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: Where do you put the first code? in the views?

Comment: yes, `get_queryset` of `getActors` view, and also change serializer of `getActors` to `GenreNoMovies`

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field "movie" on serializer "GenreNoMovies".\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the "dict" instance.\nOriginal exception text was: "movie".`

Comment: Do you edit `GenreNoMovies` Serializer? the above query is only supposed to give `genre ` and `no_of_movies ` so it does not have any movie field

Comment: is there any possibility to keep all that info?

Comment: can you edit your question and explicitly specify a `json` how you want your response

Comment: Please check the desired result. There are additional stuff, so the code should allow me to add them too...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249940/discussion-between-k4anubhav-and-vagner).

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to implement this route, it depends on many criteria and how much it will be used .

i think a correct way is to create a dedicated model that would store actor stats with a one to one relation to actor and recompute the value each time a movie is added. But If you add movie often it could slow down your database.

You can also accept to have some outdated data for a while and update the table regularly using a background job and maybe using custom sql query that will ensure you better performance (bulk update).

Answer (score 0):

I would start from your model, you have genres defined as a CharField in two of your models. By not isolating them anywhere, you need to look in both tables for all types of genres. If do not, then you are just supposing that all the genres you have in one table is also on the other one, which could not be true.

Also, querying string fields is not very efficient when in comparison to a int PK, so from the point of view of scaling this is bad. (Of course, i am saying that in general, as a good practice and not focused specifically in movie genres)

Your best option would be to have either a Genre Model or a [choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices), where you define all possible genres.

As for the counting, you would do that inside your serializer class, by using a [serializermethodfield](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).